# How to create a SPARQL query to search Wikidata item descriptions

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-query-service

I'd like to be able to find an item based on words in its descriptions.

This is what I'm trying to do, but clearly I don't know what I'm doing. Any help is appreciated.

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel WHERE {
 
  ?item schema:description ?desc.
  FILTER(CONTAINS(LCASE(?desc), "space telescope"))
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}

LIMIT 10
```

Comment: in theory correct, but do to the size of the dataset rather inefficient as no fulltex index is used but a full scan on all entities. You can use the MediaWiki extensions,

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?dateOfBirth 
WHERE {
  hint:Query hint:optimizer "None".
  SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "Search";
                    wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org";
                    mwapi:srsearch "space telescope".
    ?item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:title .
  }
  
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
limit 10`

Comment: or this search entry point:

Comment: `SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?type ?typeLabel WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
      bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "EntitySearch" .
      bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org" .
      bd:serviceParam mwapi:search "space telescope" .
      bd:serviceParam mwapi:language "en" .
      ?item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item .
      ?num wikibase:apiOrdinal true .
  }
  ?item (wdt:P279|wdt:P31) ?type
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }

} ORDER BY ASC(?num) LIMIT 10`

Comment: indeed, you could add a triple pattern that does filter on specific types or at least omits e.g. scholarly articles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved by UninformedUser in the comments!**

```
WHERE {   hint:Query hint:optimizer "None".   
       SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {     
         bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "Search";                     
         wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org";                     
         mwapi:srsearch "space telescope".     
         ?item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:title .   }      
         SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". } 
         
} 

limit 10
```